# podman-compose failing to compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, podman

I realize podman-compose is still under development.  I'm going to be replacing my docker stack with podman once I replace Debian with CentOS8 on my Poweredge server as part of my homelab.  Right now I'm just testing out/playing around with podman on my Fedora machine.

OS: Fedora 32
KERNEL:5.6.12-300.fc32.x86_64
PODMAN: 1.9.2
PODMAN-COMPOSE: 0.1.5

PROBLEM: podman-compose is failing and I'm unable to ascertain the reason why.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  deluge:
    image: linuxserver/deluge
    container_name: deluge
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/New_York
#      - UMASK_SET=022 #optional
#      - DELUGE_LOGLEVEL=error #optional
    volumes:
      - /home/mike/test/deluge:/config
      - /home/mike/Downloads:/downloads
    restart: unless-stopped
```

When I run **podman-compose up** Here is the output:

```
[mike@localhost test]$ podman-compose up
podman pod create --name=test --share net
ce389be26589efe4433db15d875844b2047ea655c43dc84dbe49f69ffabe867e
0
podman create --name=deluge --pod=test -l io.podman.compose.config-hash=123 -l io.podman.compose.project=test -l io.podman.compose.version=0.0.1 -l com.docker.compose.container-number=1 -l com.docker.compose.service=deluge --network host -e PUID=1000 -e PGID=1000 -e TZ=America/New_York --mount type=bind,source=/home/mike/test/deluge,destination=/config --mount type=bind,source=/home/mike/Downloads,destination=/downloads --add-host deluge:127.0.0.1 --add-host deluge:127.0.0.1 linuxserver/deluge
Trying to pull registry.fedoraproject.org/linuxserver/deluge...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/linuxserver/deluge...
  name unknown: Repo not found
Trying to pull registry.centos.org/linuxserver/deluge...
  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
Trying to pull docker.io/linuxserver/deluge...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob a54f3db92256 done  
Copying blob c114dc480980 done  
Copying blob d0d29aaded3d done  
Copying blob fa1dff0a3a53 done  
Copying blob 5076df76a29a done  
Copying blob a40b999f3c1e done  
Copying config 31fddfa799 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
Error: error checking path "/home/mike/test/deluge": stat /home/mike/test/deluge: no such file or directory
125
podman start -a deluge
Error: unable to find container deluge: no container with name or ID deluge found: no such container
125
```

Then finally when I quite via **ctrl-c** :

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/.local/bin/podman-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/podman_compose.py", line 1093, in main
    podman_compose.run()
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/podman_compose.py", line 625, in run
    cmd(self, args)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/podman_compose.py", line 782, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/podman_compose.py", line 914, in compose_up
    thread.join(timeout=1.0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 1005, in join
    if not self._started.is_set():
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 513, in is_set
    def is_set(self):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm not experienced enough to be able to read through this and figure out what the problem is so I'm hoping to learn from you all.

Thanks!

Comment: It says `Error: error checking path "/home/mike/test/deluge": stat /home/mike/test/deluge: no such file or directory`. That looks like your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your path:

```
volumes:
    /home/mike/test/deluge:/config
```

> /home/mike/test/deluge: no such file or directory

Check the folder path.

Comment: So, I guess I'm still thinking of docker, because as I recall, running **docker-compose up -d** would create any missing folders which were specified in the compose file.  Take the above example.  If the "deluge" folder did not exist inside /home/mike/test/ then compose would create it.  Anyway, I created the deluge folder so as to verify the path existed and now I'm getting a whole new host of errors.  Looks like a permission issue?  https://pastebin.com/raw/rvBk8Euq

Comment: Seems like permission error on the directory you have created. What are the permissions of config files in `/home/mike/test/deluge`?